# max count together in an sql query

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have the following table (simplified) in an oracle db:

```
productId  |  modelDescription 
         1 |             thing
         2 |     another thing
         3 |       not a thing
         4 |             thing
```

I want to select the modeldescription which has the highest appearence in this table. The problem is that there can be nearly infinite model descriptions. 
So the resultset should look like something like this:

```
modelDescription | appearance 
           thing |          2 
   another thing |          1 
             ... |        ...
```

Comment: By highest appearance you mean highest as sorted by productId?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select modeldescription, count(modeldescription) 
from products 
group by modeldescription
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: thaks thats exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

In addition, if you only want the highest add the following:

Select **Top 1** modeldescription......