# max count together in an sql query 2

Tags: sql, oracle10g

This is referring to the question i asked before, and got a really quick answaer ([max count together in an sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751156/max-count-together-in-an-sql-query)). The Problemset is similar, but the solution in the prevous question would force me to access a db in a loop which will cause performance problems. So what i have now, after some joins is:

```
    id | description
     0 | bla
     0 | blub
     0 | bla
     1 | blablub
     1 | bla
   ... | ...
```

As u can see, now the id is not a primary key anymore. What i want is to get the most used description for each id in the resultset. It should look something like this:

```
 id | most_popular_description | times_the_desc_appeared_for_an_id
  0 |                      bla |                                 2
  1 |                  blablub |                                 1
... |                      ... |                               ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the most popular items, then I believe this should give you the result set you're looking for.  There are other ways of doing this, but [stats_mode](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions154.htm) is the easiest way to obtain the "most prevalent" value in a group (i.e. the Mode).

```
SELECT t.id,
       t.description AS most_popular_description,
       COUNT(*) AS times_the_desc_appeared_for_an_id
FROM mytable t INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id, stats_mode(description) AS desc FROM mytable GROUP BY id
) a ON t.id = a.id AND t.description = a.desc
GROUP BY t.id, t.description;
```

Note that the nested query (inline view) is necessary since you also want the count.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.

```
select id, description, COUNT(description)
from mytable
group by id, description
order by 3 desc
```

Comment: sry but it's not quite what i wanted, still thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the dense_rank() analytic function to get the top N for each group set.

Something like this:

```
select id, description, times_the_desc_appeared_for_an_id
from
(
  select id, description, count(description) times_the_desc_appeared_for_an_id
  dense_rank() over (partition by id, description order by count(description) desc) position
  from mytable
  group by id, description
)
where
  position <= 3
order by id, times_the_desc_appeared_for_an_id;
```

Comment: havent tested it, since the solution by rwwilden works, but thanks anyway